# Data exchange between two Organization in MS CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

Is there any way through which I can exchange data between two organization.
I want to do my coding in Plugin only. Can we write a code in plugin by which it accesses/manipulates the data of a different org **through web services** only and not directly hitting its database.
In know the orgs are different worker groups. Just wanted to know if its possible or if there is any other technique.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for each CRM organisation is exposed via web services which differ slightly for CRM 2011 and CRM 4.  The best thing to do is download the latest version of the SDK for the target platform as there are several examples in there for plugins and service based operations.

From your plugin you will be able to access the other organisation via this service and a connection to the service for the "local organisation in which the plugin is running will be available from the IExecutionContext parameter passed to your plugin.  Any operations you carry out across both orgs will not be transactional though.

Also be sure to take a look at the sync and async options available for the plugins.  If their use is appropriate for your scenario consider using an async plugin for the updates to the target org to minimise their effect on the source org.

Comment: I know that IExecutionContext will provide metadata/data for the current Org which is running, how will we get the same for the other Organization? I mean I have taken references of the SDK dlls only to my Plugin solution. Also what do you mean by " Any operations you carry out across both orgs will not be transactional though". Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You will create a new connection to the same CRM server service but specify the other org. How you do this depends on the version of CRM.  The fact you're running in a plugin makes no difference as there is no shared context between orgs. You're just a client accessing the org via the service that happens to be running in another orgs plugin.  There's no transactional support as you're a separate client and CRM doesn't support distributed transactions so you won't get automatic rollback of any changes applied to the target if an error occurs in the execution of the plugin on the source server.

Answer (score 0):

Plug-ins will work. Hitting the database directly is actually not a supported model anyways. You can also think of using BizTalk as the middleware.

Comment: Thanks for replying...We can not use biztalk. How can it be done with Plugin.?